# CSS make background images misaligned

Tags: css

I've got two divs .navigation & .entry-image

```
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #008dd0;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    z-index: 100;
    color: #fff;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
}

.entry-image {
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-position: top;
}
```

The background aligns well on widescreen however set as size:cover, they do not stay aligned as they respond obviously. 
I've experimented with background-size:100% - this does not work on 100vh as it repeats.

Any suggestion on how I can keep the backgrounds aligning while still maintaining 100vh on the parent container. This is all due to the .navigation having a multiply blend mode applied which is only required behind the .navigation div

codepen: https://codepen.io/lisa-jaffe/pen/jOErBBX

Comment: Will be good if you provide an example in some code sandbox

Comment: use object-fit property and this will override the image trying to maintain its aspect ratio

Comment: try to add  background-attachment: fixed; to both elements

Comment: background-attachment: fixed works perfectly on desktop, but not on mobile devices /IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. If so:

If what you're trying to achieve is to have a sort of overlay on top of the image then instead of trying to align 2 images, which is rather difficult, you can use a proper "overlay", which is far simpler.

What I did was remove the `navigation` image and instead use a background color with transparency. You get the same result as your code but without the alignment issues.

```css
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(6, 84, 121, 0.7);
    z-index: 100;
    color: #fff;
    height:300px;
}

.entry-image {
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-position: top;
    background-image:url(https://loremflickr.com/1680/1050);
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation"></div>
<div class="entry-image"></div>
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codepen.io/obedparla/pen/gObMmoe) if you need that instead

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I'd initially tried this approach, however, the background-blend-mode: multiply; is essential which doesn't work this way.

Comment: I understand. Try adding that to your question, maybe someone has a solution